# GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY produces incorrect table schema with UCanAccess

Tags: sql, jdbc, ucanaccess

I'm writing a program using JDBC/UCanAccess and I'm finding when I create one of the tables, instead of creating four columns with the DateTime format, it also applies the same format to the next column, displacing the other formats:

```
CREATE TABLE Person (
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1), 
    Name VARCHAR(40), 
    Surname VARCHAR(40), 
    Card VARCHAR(9), 
    Email VARCHAR(30)
);

CREATE TABLE Place (
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1), 
    Name VARCHAR(40)
);


CREATE TABLE Activity (
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1), 
    Name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, 
    Description1 VARCHAR(500), 
    Description2 VARCHAR(500), 
    Id_Person INT, 
    Hour_Start DATETIME, 
    Hour_End DATETIME, 
    Date_Plan_Start DATETIME, 
    Date_Plan_End DATETIME, 
    Cost CURRENCY, 
    Sale CURRENCY, 
    Id_Place INT, 
    CONSTRAINT fk_person_activity FOREIGN KEY (Id_Person) REFERENCES Person (Id), 
    CONSTRAINT fk_place_activity FOREIGN KEY (Id_Place) REFERENCES Place (Id)
);
```

It seems to do everything as it should up to Date_Plan_End, but the created table has Cost as a DateTime, and Id_Place as Currency. If anyone could tell me why this happens I'd appreciate it.

EDIT: The error stills happens inserting only this:

```
CREATE TABLE Activity (
    Id INT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1), 
    Name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, 
    Date_Plan_End DATETIME, 
    Cost CURRENCY, 
    Sale CURRENCY, 
    Id_Place INT, 
    PRIMARY KEY (Id)
);
```

[SQL and outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riu61.png)

The problem seems to be related to the GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1). Its removal stops the displacement from happening, although I don't know why.

Comment: So, that's the generated SQL.  Please could you show the code that ***you*** wrote that generated this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, it is not a code created by any function if that's what you're saying. I wrote it pretty much as-is. It was supposed to be part of a code that'd setup a blank database with the needed tables and a few entries for testing. The only variables involved were two to determine varchar length, and it was the first thing I changed when I saw there were errors. And given that the error also happens if I pass the SQL directly through the ucanaccess console I don't think it is a problem in the functions in the program that pass the SQL commands.

Comment: So, with the code above the column `Activity.Cost` is set as a `DATETIME`?  Could you show something that demonstrates that this has happened?  I've never seen such a symptom before on any database.  Similarly, could you try slowly simplifying the table's DDL until the symptom disappears?  *(Does it still happen if you remove the foreign keys?  Does it still happen if you remove the `VARCHAR(500)` columns?  What's the minimal example you can find where the problem remains?)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem seems to be related to the GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1). Its removal stops the displacement from happening

That's because `... GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ...` is HSQLDB DDL syntax, and UCanAccess uses Access SQL DDL syntax. Therefore instead of

```sql
CREATE TABLE Activity (
    Id INT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1), 
    Name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, 
    Date_Plan_End DATETIME, 
    Cost CURRENCY, 
    Sale CURRENCY, 
    Id_Place INT, 
    PRIMARY KEY (Id)
);
```

you should use

```sql
CREATE TABLE Activity (
    Id COUNTER PRIMARY KEY, 
    Name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, 
    Date_Plan_End DATETIME, 
    Cost CURRENCY, 
    Sale CURRENCY, 
    Id_Place INT
);
```